# Full screen desktop zooming for Gnome/KDE

Tags: linux, accessibility

Long story short, I'm going blind and I need a full screen magnifier for Linux. I've spent the better part of a few months looking around for a half decent option across many different distros and desktop environments.

The best I could find was Enhanced Desktop Zoom through Compiz; however, Compiz is not really being supported anymore so I need a different option.

It **must** be full-screen, not a windowed option like Orca.

It also must be able to activate/control using keyboard or mouse shortcuts.

Any help would be seriously appreciated. I cannot use Linux until a find a viable option.